# Servlets:Context object showing null when it is accessed from different browser

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I recently learnt that the context object won't change for different users or servlets.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    ServletContext context=request.getServletContext();
    try{
        if(username!=null && !username.isEmpty())
            session.setAttribute("savedUserName", username);
            context.setAttribute("name", username);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){

    }
    out.println("Request parameter has username: "+username);
    out.println("Session parameter has username: "+(String)session.getAttribute("savedUserName"));
    out.println("Context parameter has username: "+(String)context.getAttribute("name"));

}
```

When I set the context object using setAttribute and run my servlet it'll print the correct value.But if I try to run the servlet using different browser it's showing null.According to my knowledge context object value should work for all servlets.In the above program I'm taking the parameter from URL.What's the problem with my code?

Comment: You've probably restarted your server, or redeployed the application, between your two requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as my understanding in your code please use `{}` brackets with if condition.it will allow to set name attribute's value when unsername is not null.

in your code, `context.setAttribute("name", username);` code is outside of if condition show it's set to null value when you hit servelt from another web browser.

```
     try{
            if(username!=null && !username.isEmpty()){  
                session.setAttribute("savedUserName", username);
                context.setAttribute("name", username);
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){

        }
```